# Reason for Hdfs IO throughout limit for Executor spark

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, hdfs

I see a lot this quote in websites

> We want multi threading on each executor , at the same time throughput should also not get affected. It is observed, HDFS achieves full write throughput with ~5 tasks per executor, which means we can allot ~5 cores for each executor to get optimal performance .

My question is why this limit exists
I think each thread of executor should have own hdfs client for talking to hdfs
,so number of thread must not affect on hdfs throughput